# problems in ajax in rails 4 no change after submiting request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, jquery

I am trying to print out a url after clicking a link_to ajax link.
This is my performer_payout_display.html.erb file.

```
Get url to sign up to payoneer: <br/>
<%= link_to "Generate",controller:"performers",action:"process_payee_link",remote:true%>
<div class="url">
Url:    <%= render  'url'  %>
</div>
```

This is my performers controller

```
def performer_payout_display

end
def process_payee_link
a=Payoneer.new('100020940','Glamgirls','123456')
  var=current_user.email
@urlp=a.payee_link(var)
      respond_to do |format|
        #if (!@url.blank?)
        format.js { render :layout=>false }
      end
end
```

This is my process_payee_link.js.erb file

```
$("#url").html("<%= escape_javascript(render(:partial => "url")) %>");
```

This is my _url.html.erb file

```
<%= @urlp %>
```

There is no change in the url: part after I click the link. What seems to be the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use a jQuery id selector but in your view you have a class selector:

```
$("#url")
<div class="url">
```

Add `id='url'` to your div above.

Comment: dammit! That was very stupid of me! Thank you! I will accept it.

Comment: :).. hmmm ya it happens